# ExtJs: Need help in designing the model structure

Tags: extjs, model

I am part of a project wherein ExtJs has to be used for frontend development.
Backend developers are going to provide the apis and I have to consume it.

There are several apis which returns the json in below format

```
{
    "Entity": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Sunshine",
            "placements": 3,
            "next_meeting": "2019-03-14T16:29:00.48Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Merlon",
            "placements": 1,
            "next_meeting": "2019-03-14T16:29:00.48Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Mars",
            "placements": 10,
            "next_meeting": "2019-03-14T16:29:00.48Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Moonlight",
            "placements": 5,
            "next_meeting": "2019-03-14T16:29:00.48Z"
        }
    ],
    "RecordCount": 4,
    "IsSuccess": true,
    "Unauthorized": false,
    "ErrorInformation": {
        "Message": null,
        "Link": null
    }
}
```

As of now I am creating separate models like below
ClientModel.js

```
Ext.define('ClientModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
            name: "id",
            type: "int",
            convert: null
        },
        {
            name: "name",
            type: "string"
        },
        {
            name: "placements",
            type: "int",
            convert: null
        },
        {
            name: "next_meeting",
            type: "date",
            dateFormat: 'm/d/Y',
            convert: function(v, rec) {
                return Ext.util.Format.date(v, 'm/d/Y');
            }
        }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        url: "/api/Clients",
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            rootProperty: "Entity",
            totalProperty: "RecordCount",
            successProperty: "IsSuccess"
        }
    }
});
```

Looking for better approach as all the api returns the response in given form.

How do I create a base model which should serve as parent of other models?

I'd like to design my model like:

```
Ext.define('ParentModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {
        name: 'Entity'
    },
    {
        name: 'RecordCount',
        type: 'int'         
    },
    {
        name: 'IsSuccess',
        type: 'boolean'
    },
    {
        name: 'Unauthorized',
        type: 'boolean'
    },
    {
        name: 'ErrorInformation'
    }
]
});
```

Now lets say for the api '/api/clients' I am getting some response which depicts a Client Model so the Entity field should refer or point to ClientModel.

Similarly, lets say I have another api '/api/comments' which depicts a CommentModel, now the entity field should refer or point to CommentModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create ParentProxy:

```
Ext.define('ParentProxy', {
    alias: 'proxy.parentProxy',
    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    type: "ajax",
    url: "/api/Clients"
    reader: {
        type: "json",
        rootProperty: "Entity",
        totalProperty: "RecordCount",
        successProperty: "IsSuccess"
    }
});
```

Next you can create ParentModel:

```
Ext.define('ParentModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {
            name: "id",
            type: "int",
            convert: null
        },
        {
            name: "name",
            type: "string"
        },
        {
            name: "placements",
            type: "int",
            convert: null
        },
        {
            name: "next_meeting",
            type: "date",
            dateFormat: 'm/d/Y',
            convert: function(v, rec) {
                return Ext.util.Format.date(v, 'm/d/Y');
            }
        }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: "parentProxy"
    }
});
```

And create ChildModel (if fields are the same):

```
Ext.define('ChildModel', {
    extend: 'ParentModel',
    proxy: {
        url: "/api/ChildClients"
    }
});
```

And create ChildModel (if fields aren't the same):

```
Ext.define('ChildModel2', {
    extend: 'ParentModel',
    fields: [
        {
            name: "id",
            type: "int",
            convert: null
        },
        {
            name: "name",
            type: "string"
        },
        {
            name: "status",
            type: "int"
        }
    ],
    proxy: {
        url: "/api/ChildClients"
    }
});
```

EDIT:
In my opinion it's bad model pattern in extjs. 
One thing you can do is the association in model.

E.g. [reference](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.data.schema.Reference.html),

```
fields: [{ 
    name: 'Entity', 
    reference: 'CommentsModel'
}]
```

E.g. [hasOne](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.data.schema.HasOne.html), it look like:

```
hasOne: [{
    model: "CommentModel",
    name:"Entity",
    associationKey: "Entity"
}]
```

Comment: Thanks norbeq. I am gonna use it. However my requirement is something else.  I've updated the question

Comment: Thanks for providing your inputs with references.